# NullException: Value cannot be undefined. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, while-loop, null

```
        //get entries
        string[,] entries = Search(ReplaceBlankWithAny(
          new string[] { name, code, supplier, lot, grams, date, shelf, inStock, costKG }), 
          data);

        int length = entries.GetLength(0);
        int x = 0;

        if (entries.GetLength(1) != 0)
        {
            x = 0;
            //populate table
            //for (uint x = 0; x < entries.GetLength(0); x++) not working
            while (x < length)
            {
                string[] onlyInterestingParts = entries
                  .TakeHorizontalSlice((uint)x)
                  .Take(4)
                  .ToArray();

                Main.instance.dataGridViewMatPrime.Rows.Add(onlyInterestingParts);

                x++;
            }
        }

        return entries;
```

I tried using a for (commented in the code) and then a while but they both return the error in the title. I moved the variable x outside the if but it still doesn't work. I am sure **ENTRIES IS NOT NULL**, both because the if (entries.GetLength(1) != 0) is true and because i checked it in the debugger. Any reply is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line doe the exception happen on?

Comment: It happens on while (x < length)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was showing on while (x < length), but it was on

```
string[] onlyInterestingParts = entries
                  .TakeHorizontalSlice((uint)x)
                  .Take(4)
                  .ToArray();
```

TakeHorizontalSlice((uint)x) was returning null